# Find files with pattern and get latest one

Tags: find, filenames

I want to find file with specific pattern and print the latest file matching the pattern with full path

`find ../*.gz -type f -print0 | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head -n 1`

How do I print the full path of the same.

As requested by users `ls -l`:

```
ls -l
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Jun 27 23:29 fa1caae85
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Jun 27 23:28 ga1c93eda
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Jun 27 23:28 la1cbbh05
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Jun 27 23:08 node_modules
drwxrwxr-x 3 xxx xxx 4096 Jun 27 23:08 _tasks
```

All top three folders contains require `.gz` files, however I want to get latest `.gz` file out of them.

Comment: @Rahul, yes. I guess my pattern is `*.gz`

Comment: You do realize that `find ../*.gz` doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: @SatoKatsura, didn't get you. Can you explain plz

Comment: @Rahul, I am searching for that file in sub-directories.

Comment: @Rahul, yes. I updated the OP with your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using this command,

```
find "$(pwd)" -type f -name "*.gz" -printf "%T@ %p\n"| sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f 2- | head -n 1
```

That assumes GNU `find`, that the path names don't contain newline characters and that file names are valid text in the locale. To handle newlines and non-characters, you could change it to:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.gz' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
    sort -zrn | head -zn 1 | cut -zf 2- | tr '\0' '\n'
)
```

assuming relatively recent versions of GNU utilities. That is use NUL delimited records instead of lines (newline delimited records) as NUL is the only character that cannot occur in a file path.

We avoid command substitution (`$(pwd)`) which strips trailing newline characters, by using the `$PWD` variable (which contains the path to the current working directory in POSIX shells).

Switching the locale to `C` (here locally in a subshell environment `(...)`) ensures every byte is always considered a character (it also simplifies sorting and text processing in general).

Comment: it still prints relative path.

Comment: @Reddy try updated one

Comment: worked out. Thanks. is it `head` or `tail`

Comment: @Reddy you have used `sort -nr | head -n 1` and I have just used `sort -n | tail -n 1`, both are one and the same thing.

Comment: @Reddy If any of answer helped you, consider accepting it by clicking on right mark below arrow.

Comment: #Rahul, missed that one char. I was just wondering myself is it `head` or `tail`. Thanks for  pointing

Answer (score 3):

Unorthodox approach:

```
zsh -c 'print -r $PWD/**/*.gz(.om[1])'
```

where

- `()` after `*.gz` means to use so called glob qualifiers, i.e.:
- `.` consider only plain files
- `om` sort by modification time
- `[1]` take only first element
- add the `D` qualifier to also consider hidden gz files (like `find` does).

Obviously if you are already using zsh you don't need to call it with `zsh -c`.

Comment: Not using `zsh`. Looking for bash solutions :)

Comment: There's nothing unorthodox about using a tool that supports the functionality that you require.

Answer (score 0):

This worked nicely for me:

```bsh
ls -t ../*.gz | head -n1
```

From `man ls`:

```
  -t                         sort by modification time, newest first
```